# How to find after first 7 digits are zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

How to check in sql below

1. If `EMPLOYEE_NO = 0`, set target field to blank
2. If `EMPLOYEE_NO` begins with 9990, set target field to last eight digits
3. If `EMPLOYEE_NO` is 6 digits or less, set target field to complete value in `EMPLOYEE_NO`
4. If `EMPLOYEE_NO` is 7 digits or more, 
   a.  If digits after the first 7 are zeros, set target field to positions 2 thru 7
   b.  If digits after the first 7 are not zeros, set target field to positions 5 thru 10

I just write query like

```
  SELECT CASE WHEN EMPLOYEE_NO = '9990%' THEN  RIGHT(EMPLOYEE_NO,8)
    CASE WHEN LENGTH(EMPLOYEE_NO) <=6 THEN PE_EMPLOYEE_NO
    CASE WHEN LENGTH(EMPLOYEE_NO) >=7
```

But how do I write query for point 4 and 5.

Comment: Well what database platform - both?

Comment: The conditions don't make sense (as a group). If employee_no is eight digits, all of them non-zero, you are supposed to use rule #4. In that case, what are digits 5-10? The number is only eight digits.

Answer (score 2):

```
  SELECT CASE WHEN EMPLOYEE_NO = '9990%' THEN  RIGHT(EMPLOYEE_NO,8)
    CASE WHEN LENGTH(EMPLOYEE_NO) <=6 THEN PE_EMPLOYEE_NO
    CASE WHEN LENGTH(EMPLOYEE_NO) >=7 then case
               when SUBSTRING(EMPLOYEE_NO,8,1)='0' then SUBSTRING(EMPLOYEE_NO,2,6)
               else SUBSTRING(EMPLOYEE_NO,5,6) end
    END Emp_CODE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EMPLOYEE_NO like '9990%' THEN  RIGHT(EMPLOYEE_NO,8)
            WHEN LENGTH(EMPLOYEE_NO) <=6 THEN PE_EMPLOYEE_NO
            WHEN LENGTH(EMPLOYEE_NO) >=7 THEN
                 CASE WHEN SELECT MID(EMPLOYEE_NO ,7,LENGTH(EMPLOYEE_NO)) like                       '%0' then  MID(EMPLOYEE_NO ,2,7) else MID(EMPLOYEE_NO ,5,10) end
 end as Employee_ID from ....
```

Comment: This works better than my answer if using sql server as it also handles alpha characters.  I didnt know the like worked this way its good to know.  I will upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This question is tagged as both Sql-Server and Oracle.  Depending on Oracle or Sql Server the syntax would be different but here is the general idea.

You need to have two case lines for > 7 with an And included.  You first have to isolate the string after the 7th character using a substring function.  This value can be evaluated to contain all 0's or not depending on your platform syntax.

For example if I knew that this data only contained numeric digits I would code in tsql:

```
CASE WHEN LENGTH(EMPLOYEE_NO) >=7 And Convert(Int, Substring(EMPLOYEE_NO, 8, Lenght(EMPLOYEE_NO) - 7)) = 0 Then...
CASE WHEN LENGTH(EMPLOYEE_NO) >=7 And Convert(Int, Substring(EMPLOYEE_NO, 8, Lenght(EMPLOYEE_NO) - 7)) > 0 Then...
```

Comment: Looking at the other answers posted while I was writing mine I will say that you can indeed use a nested case but if you want to ensure that all digits after the 7th are 0 you need to do more.  My answer would work if every digit was guaranteed numeric, if alpha characters are involved it would take a bit more work maybe a scalar function.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Emp TABLE (EMPLOYEE_NO VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @Emp VALUES ('12345670000000'),('12345670004000')

SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(EMPLOYEE_NO) >=7 THEN 
            CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[1-9]%',SUBSTRING (EMPLOYEE_NO,8,LEN(EMPLOYEE_NO)-7)) = 0 
                THEN SUBSTRING(EMPLOYEE_NO,2,5)
                ELSE SUBSTRING(EMPLOYEE_NO,5,5)
                END
        END
FROM @Emp
```

For this - If digits after the first 7 are zeros - I used PATINDEX to check if there are any 0s and based on that used the SUBSTRING function